# Random "null"s appearing all over the reputation report in IE8?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Hey all-

I just went to my reputation report and saw this:

[image]

Notice how there's many copies of "null" at the far left.  When I refresh the page, they disappear for a while, but then come back when the page finishes loading.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: consider it a reminder to upgrade to IE9, which is now final and available for download! http://microsoft.com/ie9 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd ...

I always thought `<tr>null<td>` was valid html :)

Will be fixed shortly

Comment: Thanks!  Works like a charm now.  Might I ask what the root cause was?

Comment: There was a trivial bug there ... but chrome is so forgiving, it does not render it. was a javascript bug we missed